# Умное сворачивание js сайдбаров

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 2 сайдбара. Левый/правый, оба она сворачиваются/разворачиваются. Но задача состоит в том чтобы при ширине обертки <1500px выполнялись чуть другие условия , а именно:

У меня экран 1280px - при заходе на сайт развернут только левый сайдбар (то есть правый при таком разрешении скрыт) (по умолчанию (>1500px) оба сайдбара развернуты). При попытке развернуть правый, сворачивается левый , и открывается правый. и наоборот.

Так как js , я только постепенно начинаю изучать, набросал мега костильный вариант.

Как реализовать это более правильно и не костыльно?

Ссылка на jsfiddle в комментарии. (Ибо сюда не помещается, css чистить очень долго.)
Чтобы все заработало подвигайте шторку которая растягивает 4-ое окно (окно результата)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/typfu6Lr/

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей проблемы используйте свойство @media. Пример:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .сontent {
        witdh: 768px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .сontent {
        witdh: 1200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Эм, вообще мимо.

Comment: @kiLLro тогда добавьте адекватный пример и напишите нормально.

Comment: я не достаточно подробно обьяснил? Я просто попросил помочь переписать/оптимизировать js код.